# How do you manage big environments with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, development-environment

so I'm currently developing a distributed system with microservices and I'm running out of memory to run all of them in my laptop. I wonder how other people manage this situation. Is there a way to configure docker-compose to run some of them in a remote machine but keep behavior as if they were on my laptop (for inter-service communication)?

I know that I might achieve it with k8s but it seems to be so much burden for day-to-day development flow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 1):

well if it's about day to day development, then you can figure out only the most essential services to run on your system. even if with the most essential microservices you are getting out of memory then you know the answer that you can't run them all on your local machine, unless you increase your resources or you can try [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/) (similar to k8s but a bit easier).

docker swarm - you will need to create a cluster among multiple machines and you will be able to offload some of the services on the other machines within the cluster.

Also, you will need to do minor changes in your docker-compose file to run on the docker swarm.